# Как выводить контент в зависимости от геолокации пользователя? PHP

Tags: php, ip, геолокация

Подскажите пожалуйста каким образом происходит определение геолокации пользователя на сайте и вывод контента на соответствующем необходимом языке? Интересует всего 2 языка: английский и русский, не больше... Страны постсоветского пространства - русский язык, остальные - английский!

Помимо определения геопозиции, если нетрудно, не могли бы в том числе поведать о том, как реализовать соответсвующие локали на разных поддоменах (.ru/.en) и поделиться какой-нибудь полезной информацией о взаимодействии поисковиков с запросами по данному сайту из разных стран)

Достаточно даже будет наводки, про что почитать, чем воспользоваться для решения 2 задач (определение гео + реализация на поддоменах).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно подключить яндекс библиотеку yandex.map и вызвать метод geolocation, определяет на том языке какой хотите. Можно определить город, регион и страну

Подключаете в head

```
https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0-stable/?load=package.full&lang=ru-RU
```

и потом в js файле:

```
ymaps.ready(function() {
      var geolocation = ymaps.geolocation;

      alert(geolocation.city); //geolocation.region, geolocation.country
});
```

Comment: большое спасибо за ответ) А что касается последующих действий, не могли бы сориентировать, данные полученные js из yandex api как завязать на поддоменах (редиректом с оновного сайта, я так понимаю) и соответсвенно вывести необходимую информацию которая формируется php (парсеры кратко говоря). Если несложно не могли бы вкратце просто порядок взаимодейтвия описать) спасибо большое!

Comment: @ArtyomSosonko, определяете местоположение, сохраняете в куки и из php можете обращаться от куда угодно и делать что пожелаете.